# The equals implementation in Object

Tags: java, equals, equality

I was reading about the equals method in Java, and I heard people say that `==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object). `.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").

I believe it is true but, If you look at the source code for `.equals()`, it simply defers to `==`

From the Object class:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Now I am confused. What I see is we are testing if the current object have the same reference to the explicit parameter. Does it test for reference equality or for value equality?

Comment: `equals` is meant to be overridden in sub-classes of `Object`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))? It seems fairly clear about why `Object#equals` uses `==`...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I would like to know about String comparison I see people use it all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> The equals method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-`null` reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns `true` if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`).

`Object` being the ultimate base class, this is the only definition of `equals` it can provide. There are no fields to compare across instances, so an instance can only be equal to itself.

---

In a comment you've said:

> I would like to know about String comparison I see people use it all the time

Your question asks about `Object`, not `String`. `String` overrides `equals`, because `Object`'s definition of `equals` isn't appropriate for `String`. Consequently, `String` defines its own (in keeping with the semantics required for `equals` implementations).

Comment: In fairness, the documentation is not explicit about the need to override the method, although a simple google search would have resolved OP's dilemma.

Comment: @Mena - A note about that in the docs wouldn't hurt, but of course, you don't *have* to override it. It's just like any other method: If the superclass's version works for your class, it's fine to leave it alone. For lots of classes, `Object`'s definition is just fine. :-)

Comment: Totally agreed, you don't *have* to override it - you may need to. Only the documentation doesn't state that overriding is the desirable way to implement non-reference-based equality checks (which again, is pretty easy to figure out on your own). So yes, "wouldn't hurt" but good as is.

Answer (score 1):

Object doesn't have a value to compare anything with.

But in order to make sense, it has to provide an implementation for methods such as equals() or hashCode().

So, to be precise: classes deriving from Object should override equals() in case they to replace reference equality with "value semantics".